# How to use Stanford Parser to get POS tags using java?

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp, speech

I am working on a project for plagiarism detection. I need to use Stanford Parser API to get Part of Speech (POS) tags for words in sentences stored in a text file.

I understand that the class `edu.Stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser` can be used for this purpose. But I am unable to get it working.

Can anyone please tell me how I can write a code in java that can make use of this class or some other class available in the API to get POS tags?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Look at the starter files `ParserDemo.java` and `ParserDemo2.java` included in the distribution. They show simple examples of calling the parser in code. In particular, in `ParserDemo2.java` see the call `parse.taggedYield()`, which returns a `List` of `TaggedWord` from which you can ask for the `tag()` of each item.

However, if all you want is a part-of-speech tagger, you will find it is faster and less memory intensive to just use a part-of-speech tagger, such as the [Stanford Part-of-Speech Tagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc can be found here: `http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/package-summary.html`. Note that the package name (`edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser` ) is case-sensitive and you have written `Stanford`. This will mean you get "ClassNotFoundException".

You don't give any other information or error messages so it is difficult to give further help. Do you need help compiling and running Java packages? If so, solve that before tackling the NLP.